# How to render Form Choices manually

Tags: django, django-widget

I have in **form.py**

```
SELECT_PRODUCT = [
    ('item1', 'item1'),
    ('item2', 'item2'),
    ('item3', 'item3'),
    ('item4', 'item4'),
]

class OrderBonus(forms.Form):
    select_product = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=SELECT_PRODUCT ))
```

in html i need to render each choice individually:

```
<select name="{{ form_bonus.select_product .name }}">
    <option value="{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.0}}">{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.0}}</option>
    <option value="{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.1}}">{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.1}}</option>
    <option value="{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.2}}">{{form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.2}}</option>
 </select>
```

I try different ways:
1) `form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.0`
2) `form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.[0]`
3) `form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.("0")`

I try iteration:

```
{% for choice in form_bonus.select_product.field.choices %}
    {{ choice }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for value, text in form_bonus.select_product.field.choices %}
    {{ value}} - {{ text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Anyone know how maybe overwrite the Select Widget to use each choice:
`form_bonus.select_product.field.choice.0` ect.

Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="{{ form_bonus.select_product.name }}">
    {% for choice in form_bonus.select_product.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{ choice.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But make sure to use `ChoiceField` instead of `CharField`:

```
class OrderBonus(forms.Form):
    select_product = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SELECT_PRODUCT)
```

You could simply write `{{ form_bonus.as_p }}` instead of loop if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render manually a choicefield and have it correctly rendered with the right selected choice, you'd better use the `subwidgets` attribute instead. In this case, it's not totally manually done, though !

```
<select name="{{ form_bonus.select_product.name }}">
    {% for widget in form_bonus.select_product.subwidgets %}
        {{ widget }}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```